# Storing and processing RPG Weapons, Spells, Classes C#

Tags: c#

So I've got a text-based RPG I've been brainstorming over with a few of my friends. We've got the whole principle down. Here's how it'll work:

- Spells will be split between classes (Warrior, Mage, Rogue etc)
- Each player can select let's say 3 spells to use in battle of the class specific let's say 10.

The problem that I've got at the moment is that I have no clue how to store spells. I could just do this:

```cs
public interface IClass {
   string name {get; set;}
   //some other features
}
public class Warrior : IClass {
   public string name {get; set;} = "Warrior";
   //again, some other features
}
public interface ISpell {
   string name {get; set;}
   IClass classReq {get; set;}
   string description {get; set;}
   double CalculateDamage(double d);
}
public class SlamAttack : ISpell {
   public string name {get; set;} = "Slam Attack";
   public IClass classReq {get; set;} = new Warrior();
   public string description {get; set;} = "Do 10 damage, then Stun the target";
   double CalculateDamage(double d) {} //Do what description says
}
public class MagicBoltThing : ISpell {
   public string name {get; set;} = "Magic Bolt";
   public IClass classReq {get; set;} = new Wizard(); //Just another class
   public string description {get; set;} = "Do 12-15 damage";
   double CalculateDamage(double d) {} //Do what description says
}
//and soooo on
```

This last part is what I would've loved to avoid (defining 40 different classes just so each `CalculateDamage()` does something different), but I gave up on that. So I decided to something with a database, but I never worked with databases before, so I just did somethin like this, and use it with reflection:

```
SpellID | SpellName   | SpellClass
---------------------------------------
1       | Magic Bolt  | MagicBoltThing
2       | Slam Attack | SlamAttack
```

Reflection part looks somethin like this:

```cs
var type = Type.GetType($"MyNameSpace.Spells.{spellNanme}"); //spellName is just the name of the spell I got from the user by typing into the console for example
dynamic spell = Activator.CreateInstance(type); //dynamic is the only way I managed to get this to work, because for some reason casting, broke the entire thing
```

So is there a better way of going about this... entire thing. It feels extremely clunky and it's kinda hard to work with + apparently a lot of ppl here say that to not use reflection. So is there a better way to store and proccess spells (either a better way of storage than a database, or better way to get classes from a string other than reflection)?

Comment: Databases is used mostly for services, if you write basic game it probably good to just store serialized classes in json files. It is also easier to read/modify/version control. I.e: *File.WriteAllText("weapons/sword.json", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(weaponClassInstance));*

Comment: So it stores instances of the classes in JSON files correct? Wouldn't that require me to initialize an instance of every class first? Like the first few lines of my code would just be `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new MagicBoltThing());` then `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new SlamAttack());` etc.

Comment: Yes you do need to initialize them, but that can be done manually, just like you draw image - you specify weapon parameters.

Comment: I've been lookin for a JsonConvert.SerializeObject, but I haven't found one. But I did find a JsonSerializer.Serialize in System.Text.Json. Are those the same or which namespace does that class belong to?

Comment: It would help us if you tagged your question with the platform you're developing this in, e.g. .NET Core or .NET Framework. Since `System.Text.Json` only exists in Core 3.0 and up I'm assuming that's what you're using, in which case the answer is yes, you can and should use that class.

Comment: Some tips/suggestions regarding your current class structure: instead of having `ISpell.classReq` be an `IClass`, define a `ClassType` enumeration and use that instead. As for the individual spells, there probably isn't a need to have a separate class for each one - for example, a lot of spells are going to do a flat amount of damage and nothing else, so for those you can have a single class that just reads its name and damage values from the DB, and then you construct an instance of said class for each spell row in the DB.